# extending aoColumnDefs by multiple classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I want tables with class `.table-currency` to have a few columns with a `sType: currency` in my dataTables,

Tables with `.table-checkable` which have a checkbox in the first column should have the 1st column not sortable

I have this code

```
// Checkable Tables
if (self.hasClass('table-checkable')) {
    $.extend(true, options, {
        'aoColumnDefs': [
            { 'bSortable': false, 'aTargets': [0] }
        ]
    });
}

// Currency fields
if (self.hasClass('table-currency')) {

    var columns = self.data('currency');

    $.extend(true, options, {
        "aoColumnDefs": [
            {"sType": "currency", "bSortable": true, "aTargets": columns}
        ]
    });    
}
```

Now, when a table has **both** `.table-checkable` and `.table-currency`, it only applies the currency rule because it overwrites the `aoColumnDefs`..

How do I make it so that the `aoColumnDefs` array gets merged?

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution myself, by defining `options.aoColumnDefs` first, and `.push`'ing fields to it.

```
options.aoColumnDefs = [];

// Checkable Tables
if (self.hasClass('table-checkable')) {
    options.aoColumnDefs.push({ 'bSortable': false, 'aTargets': [0] });
}

// Currency fields
if (self.hasClass('table-currency')) {
    var columns = self.data('currency');
    options.aoColumnDefs.push({"sType": "currency", "bSortable": true, "aTargets": columns});
}
```